# SAML2: SP/idP metadata loaded by URL safe or not?

Tags: saml-2.0

I am managing an SAML2 enabled idP, and now I need to **import an SP into the idP server**.

Usually I will just download the xml from the SP, and import it into our idP.

However, I was reading a documentation which said it is possible to just use HTTP(s) to load the metadata to our idP. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-idp-http)

Which seems more convenient (no need to manually re-cert), but I am concerning whether this will lower our security.

So my question is, **is it safe to load SP/idP metadata by URL**? If so, any reason behind it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how you get it is secondary to how you validate it. The metadata should be signed by the issuer and your IdP, when it automatically downloads it, should verify the signature on it. A lot of IdPs use the [UK Federation metadata](https://www.ukfederation.org.uk/content/Documents/OperationalInfo) url to automatically ingest/update SP metadata. The metadata is signed by the federation so the IdPs can verify its integrity.